# FirebaseUser is not null after anonymous authentication is signed out

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have 2 activities in my app. I also have a sign-in button that when clicked this method is called:

```
private void signIn() {
    firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously().addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (firebaseUser != null) {
                goToSecondActivity();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This my `goToSecondActivity()` method:

```
private void goToSecondActivity() {
    startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

As specified in the [official doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth), in `onStart()`, I check the `firebaseUser` object for nullity like this:

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
if (firebaseUser != null) {
    goToMapActivity();
}
```

In the second activity I'm trying to get the uid of the user like this:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

If I try to print this uid, everything works fine, the uid is printed. If I try to sign-out (in the SecondActivity) and sign-in again, a new uid is generated, which is correct. The problem is if I sign-out again and uninstall the app and launch it again, an old user is used, even if I wait for 5 hours.

How can I solve this, so if I sign-out, next time I use my app to use the last generated user and not a very old one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Android 6 has the automatic backup. You need to tune `android:allowBackup` and `android:fullBackupContent` in your manifest `application>` tag if you don't want your data backed up or if you want to include or exclude some resources. It's not a bug.

You can find more info [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup)

In short to avoid this behaviour it is necessary to put `android:allowBackup="false"` and `android:fullBackupContent="false"` in manifest.xml